# Refactoring process of code

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, refactoring

**Context:** Currently I am on a refactoring process of spring + hibernate source code. I have a query related to the most preferable method in the following scenarios.

**Question:** Which is better while passing value from a Controller class to Service interface, pass as different parameters or as a class object ? [In terms of memory,re-usability,etc]

**Example:**

```
myservice.getUser(login,password,....)
```

Or

```
myservice.getUser(userObj)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO there are tradeoffs to each approach, but usually I try to use model objects (= 'User', 'Product' ... that makes sense from a human perspective).
Tradeoff points I can think of:

1) memory & garbage collection: 'User' object is slightly more expensive, requires allocation on the heap, but it shouldn't be a bottleneck in most IT apps. Plus GC is good at handling such short-lived objects.

2) 'User' is good for future extension & readability: if you ever need more user details (account, country of residence...) than it's good to have an encapsulated User, otherwise your service signature will become a nightmare...

3) polymorphism: if you encapsulate into 'User', there might be different User types (e.g. "FreeUser", "VIPUser"), where your service doesn't care what exact type it gets as long as they all provide 'user.isEntitledForDiscount()'

4) I have a serious dilemma with partially populated objects. I.e. if I have a "User" model with many properties (email, employment history...), but some services require only a **fraction** of them (e.g. 'login' only requires username+password). If I use a partially populated User - it would confuse future maintainers of my code. So I either use dedicated LoginDetails object, or flattened params: login(user,password). I don't have any magic solutions except moving to node.js ;)

Comment: For the future extension & better  readability purposes, I'm go a head with the encapsulated class objects.

Comment: thanks for the update:) just wanted to emphasize section 4 again, if you're really talking about login (and it wasn't just an example) it might be very different from your general User model... anyway thanks and best of luck.